# Composition series of finite length modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Given a field $K$ of characteristic zero.
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $K$-vector space and let ${f} \in End_K(V)$. Then $V$  can be regarded as a $K[X]$-module by the action: $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i .v=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_if^i(v).$$
The  $K[X]$-module ($V,f$) is of finite length noting that the sub modules of such a module are the $f$-invariant subspaces of $V$. I was wondered if I can construct the composition series of such a module.

Any reference would be great for me.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Since $K[X]$ is a PID, you can decompose $V$ using the standard theory of modules over PID. This theory applied to matrices is just the Jordan\Rational form. I suggest that you start there.